# Listview disappears using smarthphone in landscape

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I would like to take a question about the listview.
I'm using the listview that displays the names of youtube videos, when clicked on the name is redirected to the YouTube API.
When I use the system in landscape the listview disappears and you return a screen before and then access the videos again.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: you need to handle the orientation change, it´s like the app would restart so you need to reinitialise adapters, data etc. you can use a bundle to store some data https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: first read about android life cycle,what happened when anyone rotates the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When device screen orientaion changes, system recreate your activity. You should handle it correctly

Read official documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

And lastly, do not use ListView, use RecyclerView. It is more powerfull, stable and scalable

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention configChanges inside Activity at manifest.

android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"

You are going for recyclerview. Please refer this,
https://github.com/JayaprakashR-Zealot/Knowledge-Circle---Android/tree/master/FlexiListview